# How to add custom token authorization for some endpoints in a spring oauth2 resource server

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have this simple oauth2  spring configuration where the JWT gets validated with an issuer uri.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("User", "Client")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
        return http.build()
    }

    private fun jwtAuthenticationConverter(): Converter<Jwt?, out AbstractAuthenticationToken?> {
        val jwtConverter = JwtAuthenticationConverter()
        jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(KeycloakRealmRoleConverter())
        return jwtConverter
    }
}
```

Now for 1 endpoint i need custom token validation. I see 2 ways.

1. Hardcode a token as a secret and check if thats the bearer token for that endpoint
2. Create a custom login where u get returned a long time token.

Anyways i need a custom token. Lets say i go for solution 1.
How can i for an antmatcher have custom check.
So that i can check if the token is the secret saved as environment variable.

```
antMatchers("/api/custom/players").CHECK with System.env("PLAYERS_TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide enough details about what your access-control rules should be from the business point of view, so I'll provide more concepts than specific implementation details.

As you are using JWTs, I would say that all the data required for access-control should be stored in the token. This requires you to configure **authorization-server** (Keycloak) to add relevant data in private claims. In Keycloak this is done with "mappers". Sample in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/proxies-keycloak-mapper) (pay attention to Maven dependencies, implemented interfaces and resource files).

What I understand from your need is you have "players" who subscribe for a time limited access

- create a REST API to expose subscriptions data (GET request which returns what a given player has subscribed to and until when it is valid)
- declare a "confidential" client in Keycloak to authenticate with client-credentials with a dedicated role to access this data
- create a Keycloak mapper which queries this endpoint when a user logs in and adds returned value as private claim to access-tokens (using the above declared confidential client with client-credentials flow).

Once you have all of required player data in the access-token, you can provide your own implementation of `AbstractAuthenticationToken` (using `jwtAuthenticationConverter` bean as you already do, just returning your own impl instead of `JwtAuthenticationToken`). An implementation of your own would permit to hide private claims parsing from the rest of the code and help to write "readable" `@PreAuthorize` security expressions. Sample of such a custom authentication implementation in [this other module of the same repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/security). Sample usage in security expression (`username` is a `@PathVariable`):

```java
@PreAuthorize("is(#username) or isNice() or onBehalfOf(#username).can('GREET')")
```

#### Edit

If you want to authenticate trusted clients without the context of a resource-owner ("real user") then this clients should use client-credentials flow to fetch access tokens from Keycloak:

- declare "confidential" clients in Keycloak (a different one for each client) and activate client credentials for them
- assign required roles to those clients
- configure clients to authenticate against authorization-server to fetch access-tokens with client credentials flow and send it as Bearer authorization header with their requests to resource-server as normal.

From resource-server point of view, there will be no difference: all of the requests will be authorized with access-tokens issued by the same authorization-server.

Comment: All current users use their AD account to login on client side and send the JWT token which i check in my rest api.
Some clients dont have AD accounts since no real user uses them. I need them to be able to access a few endpoints. One think could be if i could protect those endpoints with a hardcoded secret which they send every api request. Need help on how to combine something like that with current method. Anyways im going to need one more authorization method.

Comment: You're trying to invent client-credentials flow. See my edit to use it instead.

Comment: I am not using keycloak.

Comment: Why are you using KeycliakRealmRolesAuthotituesConverter, then? Client-credentials is an OAuth2 flow. Any authorization-server should support it.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Active Directory. The JWT gets validated against an issuer uri

Comment: The KeycloakRealmRoleConverter is just a misnamed converter to prefix every role with ROLE_<role>.

Comment: I just need to add some way of Authorizing JWT for non Windows AD users. One alternative im looking at is in memory authentication.

Comment: I don't get it. JWTs are issued by authorization-servers which sign it. Resource-servers need authorization-server public key to validate JWTs. The flow used to grant a JWT makes no difference to resource-server (authorization code for users from AD or client-credentials for trusted clients) : JWTs are tokens, each with claims, an issuer and a signature by this issuer (authorization-server) for those claims. And this is just the way OAuth2 works. Keycloak, MS Identity-Server, Auth0, Octa, all support it.

Comment: Yeah thats working perfectly fine. I need to secure some endpoints with another strategy. I cant get the JWT from the issuer. So i am trying to find some quick way to do this without the issuer etc

Comment: Your question is literally "how to add custom token validation ..." and now you say you have no token? Any reason why you can't fetch a token?